# Каким образом тестировать с помощью IDE+Xdebug, http запросы отправляет 1С

Tags: php, 1с, xdebug

1C Предприятие отправляет http-запросы на локальный веб-сервер "Open Server".
Xdebug настроен с IDE phpStorm в режиме "по запросу" (get-параметр или cookie). Запросы с браузера могу тестировать(debuging). 
Передаю из 1С запрос с cookie параметром XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM - не срабатывает.
Попробовал с remote_autostart настройкой Xdebug - опять не работает.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я упускаю из внимания?

Answer (score 1):

Сначала с remote_autostart не срабатывал, потому что код, который я хотел дебажить - кривой. В чем проблема, пока не выяснил. Но это уже совсем другая история.
В итоге с remote_autostart = 1 дебажить возможно. В принципе и get-параметр, и куки из 1С можно передавать и дебажить.

p.s. Как мне быть? Удалить вопрос?